# Django URLS Slugs Multiple Paths

Tags: python, django, url, slug

I am working on a website with Django that has one template for a model class that has two items in the database, categoryone and categorytwo, but I need the index.html template to link to different urls for each item of the model class, so one url path for categoryone and another for categorytwo, as they are both different sections of a website with the same index template, how can I do this using only one template? Thank you!

models.py

```
    class PostSection(models.Model):
        section_heading = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        section_desc = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
    
        class Meta:
            ordering = ['section_heading']
            verbose_name_plural = 'Content Section'
    
        def __str__(self):
            return f"{self.section_heading}"

    class Post(models.Model):
        post_section = models.ForeignKey(PostSection, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="posts")
        post_heading = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
        post_desc = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
        post_img = models.ImageField(upload_to= 'media', blank=True, null=True)
        post_highlight_img = models.ImageField(upload_to= 'highlights', blank=True, null=True)
        post_highlight_desc = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
        post_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
        featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        order = models.IntegerField(blank = True, null = True)
        tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, help_text="sth", blank=True, null=True)
        slug = models.SlugField(null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.slug
    
        class Meta:
            ordering = ('order', 'post_date')
    
        def display_tag(self):
            return ', '.join([ tag.name for tag in self.tag.all()[:8] ])
        display_tag.short_description = 'Tag'
    
    def save(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    
        instance.slug = slugify(instance.post_heading)
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("architecture", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
    
    pre_save.connect(save, sender= Post)
```

views.py

````
    def index(request):
        featured_posts_list = Post.objects.filter(featured=True).order_by('-featured')[:4]
        context = {
            "postsections": PostSection.objects.all(),
            "posts": Post.objects.all(),
            "about_me_info": AboutMeInfo.objects.all(),
            "category": AboutMeCategory.objects.all(),
            "activity": AboutMeActivity.objects.all(),
            "featured_posts_list": featured_posts_list,
        }
        return render(request, "main/index.html", context)
    
    def categoryone (request, slug):
        postsection = PostSection.objects.get(pk=1)
        obj = postsection.posts.get(slug=slug) # before obj = Post.objects.get(post_heading=post_heading) #
        context = {
            "object": obj,
        }
        return render(request, "main/templateone.html", context)
    
    def categorytwo (request, slug):
        postsection = PostSection.objects.get(pk=2)
        obj = postsection.posts.get(slug=slug) # before obj = Post.objects.get(post_heading=post_heading) #
        context = {
            "object": obj
        }
        return render(request, "main/templatetwo.html", context)```

urls.py
````

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("categoryone/<slug:slug>/", views.categoryone, name="categoryone"),
    path("categorytwo/<slug:slug>/", views. categorytwo, name="categorytwo"),
]
```

```
index.html
```

```
{% for Post in PostSection.posts.all %}
          <div class="swiper-slide" id="posts-slide">
            <a href="{{ HERE I DONT KNOW WHAT TO WRITE }}">

              <img id="posts-slide-img" src="{{ Post.post_img.url }}" alt="{{ Post.post_desc }}" style="background-color: #fff">

              <div class="slide-posts-txt">
                <h5>{{ Post.post_heading }}</h5>
                <div class="slide-posts-txt-desc">
                  <p>{{ Post.post_desc }}...</p><img src="{% static 'main/img/icn/plus-circle.svg' %}" id="read-more-plus" alt="">
                </div>
              </div>

            </a>
          </div>
          {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing your are asking about is perfectly described in django tutorials [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial03/#writing-more-views) but I would recommend you to start from the [beginning](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial01/)

Answer (score 0):

You should set the base template folder which index page will be located in working directory, in your settings.py set

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [
             os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"base_template_name")
        ],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

All the other subsequents pages will inherit from index.html